# Why conda redefines base environment after activation of another environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Here is my setup: I have 3 environments in conda:

1. default `base` environmet.
2. environment created from a command line by `conda create -n test-env python=3.7 pandas`.
3. environment create from a `.yml` file with the following command `conda env create -f environment.yml -n env-from-yml-file`.

Here is the output of `conda env list` from the `base` environment:

```sh
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\home\anaconda3
env-from-yml-file        C:\home\anaconda3\envs\env-from-yml-file
test-env                 C:\home\anaconda3\envs\test-env
```

If I activate `test-env` and then list all environments I get output, which I would expect to get: the list of my environments with asterisk near `test-env`, i.e. `conda activate test-env && conda env list`:

```sh
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\home\anaconda3
env-from-yml-file        C:\home\anaconda3\envs\env-from-yml-file
test-env              *  C:\home\anaconda3\envs\test-env
```

However, if I activate `env-from-yml-file` I get very strange results, i.e. `conda activate env-from-yml-file && conda env list`:

```sh
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\home\anaconda3
base                  *  C:\home\anaconda3\envs\env-from-yml-file
                         C:\home\anaconda3\envs\test-env
```

See that the names of environments disappeared and `env-from-yml-file` is marked as `base`.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

I did not use prefix when created environments, my conda is installed in a custom path though.

My `environment.yml` file:

```
name: sensortag-model-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - envparse
    - pipenv
  - flake8
  - pytest
  - black
  - pandas
  - conda-build
  - xlrd
  - luigi
```

Comment: Did you deactivate before activating?

Comment: I tried both with and without deactivation - same results.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was the problem of inconsistent behaviour: `conda-build` package. If this package is installed in the environment, then such environment becomes `base` after activation.

Verified it both by the command line (`conda create -n test-env-build python=3.7 pandas conda-build`) and `.yml` file.